# Issue with variables in SQlite statement WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to add / remove records within an SQlite3 database using PHP.

Adding the record:

```
$hash='d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e';
$tag='foo';

$addtag = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (hash, tags) VALUES (:hash, :tags)");
    $addtag -> bindParam(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addtag -> bindParam(':tags', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if( $addtag -> execute() ){
            echo "Tag added";
        }
```

Now I want to remove the record and that works well by doing:

```
$removetag = $db -> prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE (hash= 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' AND tags= 'foo')");

        if( $removetag -> execute() ){
            echo "Tag removed!";
        }
```

I want to use variables in this statement but it does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
$removetag = $db -> prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE (:hash AND :tags)");
    $removetag -> bindParam(':hash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $removetag -> bindParam(':tags', $tag, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if( $removetag -> execute() ){
            echo "Tag removed!";
        }
```

There is no error message, it's just not removing any record.

Comment: You're not specifying the columns : `WHERE column2 = :value1 AND column2 = :value2`. You cannot pass column names or expressions in parameter bindings.

Comment: @aynber That's it!  `$removetag = $db -> prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE (hash= :hash AND tags= :tags)");` This fixed the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)